# How can I get the extents of a text without drawing it?

Tags: squib

I want to draw text in one of two places depending on whether or not it will fit in the first place. I need the extents to figure that out. My brute force idea is to draw it in the first place with #0000 color, and then check if it fit, and then draw it with the real visible color in that place or the other place. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point you can't. Drawing text is going to be unpredictable with all of the formatting stuff, wrapping, aligning, etc. The only way that Pango provides it is after the fact.

Your solution, as yucky as it is, is the best one I've got.

If there are people know more of Pango who can do this - I would be all ears.

(Full disclosure, I am the Squib dev).